# Entity Framework Core; how to use a many-to-many table's composite key as a foreign key?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

This is my first question on the website, so if something seems off or the syntax isn't quite right, please let me know!

The schema below allows a `player` to join a `profile` using the many-to-many table `profile-player`.

[image: SQL Diagram Schema]

The table `profile-player` contains a **composite key** for `player` and `profile` using their associated primary keys. This allows players to be part of 0 or more profiles and a profile to contain 0 or more players.

This works fine, but when normalizing the data and expanding it into something like `profile-player-inventory`, it's using the primary keys of the `profile` and `player` table when I want it to use the composite keys from the `profile-player` table. I need it to use the composite key from the `profile-player` as it will cascade delete other rows such as in `profile-player-inventory` when the relationship is broken.

I've tried using the FluentAPI that EF Core provides to set its relationship, but I don't see any setting to physically change it to use the `profile-player` table's foreign key. It only allows me to set it to the `profile` or `player` table as shown below.

```cs
public sealed class ProfilePlayerInventoryConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ProfilePlayerInventoryEntity>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ProfilePlayerInventoryEntity> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("profile_player_inventory");

        builder.HasKey(x => new { x.PlayerId, x.ProfileId });

        builder.HasOne(x => x.Profile).WithMany(x => x.ProfilePlayerInventorySet);
        builder.HasOne(x => x.Player).WithMany(x => x.ProfilePlayerInventorySet);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, the fix was pretty straight forward.

I decided to change my `profile-player` table to be an auto-incrementing key with the `player-id` and `profile-id` being unique indexes instead.

The `profile-player-inventory` now references the `profile-player` as I wanted it to as in the picture attached.

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttTAv.png)